# String#split method confusion

Tags: java, string, split

I tried this code:

```
String str =",,,,,";
String str2=",,,,, ";
System.out.println(str.split(",").length);
System.out.println(str2.split(",").length);
```

And the output is:

```
0
6
```

The only difference is `str` value is `,,,,,` (**without** *space*) and `str2` value is `,,,,,` (**with** *space*)

Anybody can explain this?

Comment: If you want to keep trailing empty strings you can use `str.split(",", -1)`.

Comment: ah, I never know `split()` method can have `2` parameters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in `String#split()` method, trailing empty String will not included in the array result.

```
String str =",,,,,";
String str2=",,,,, ";
```

As `str.split(",")` will supposed to give you `[, , , , ,]`, It return `[]` instead, because you have a **trailing empty String** there.

Different from `str2.split(",")` it will give you

```
[, , , , , ]
          ^ //note the whitespace element
```

You may try

```
System.out.println(",,,,, ,,,,".split(",").length);
```

This will still give you the output: `6`, which is `[, , , , , ]` because after the *whitespace*, all you have is trailing empty string (therefore not included in the array result)

---

**Note:** You can keep the trailing empty strings by specifying the limit:

```
System.out.println(str.split(",", -1).length);
                                   ^ limit
```

Output :`6`

Check the [String#split Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split) for more details

Answer (score 2):

`This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.`  taken from the [String documentation.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Had your second string been `",,, ,,"` then the length would have been 4.

Hope that explains it clearly.