# Splitting by delimeter doesn't give the right answer

Tags: java

I am trying to split a string by .split() method in java. When I try to split the string below

```
     2000##Test
```

It gives me an array that contains;

```
     2000,,Test
```

But when I try to split something like this;

```
    ####
```

It gives me nothing. What I want to have is

```
    ,,,,
```

Edit : my delimeter is #

How can I achieve this.

Good day.

My java code is :

```
  String splitString = "2000##1000####";
  List<String> splitList = new ArrayList<String>();
  String[] splitValues = text.split(splitString,"#");
  for ( int i = 0;i< splitValues.length;i++){
      splitList.add(splitValues[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: text.split(splitString,"#"); that can't be right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String#split method confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681969/stringsplit-method-confusion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an addition to this and I realise it's not the question you asked, but it looks like you also want to convert your split array to a list, do this instead of the for loop you have

```
String splitString = "####";
List<String> splitList = Arrays.asList(splitString.split("#",-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and documented problem / behaviour. [`String.split()` silently discards trailing separators.](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter)

The JavaDocs of [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) (emphasis mine):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

---

The easiest way and the go-to splitting mechanism these days is to use Google Guava's [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

```
String input = "####";
System.out.println(Splitter.on('#').split(input));
```

outputs:

```
[, , , , ]
```

Also, it avoids creating the underlying array with all the results altogether as it splits lazily. This is less memory demanding, among other advantages.

Your code shows that you want to make a `List` out of the resulting array. This is also easily achievable:

```
List<String> splitInput = Splitter.on('#').splitToList(input);
```

---

You can also use [Apache Commons Lang's `StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) for this:

```
StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(input, '#');
```

also outputs `[, , , , ]`

Comment: Can I have it with apache commons ?

Comment: Yes. Edited it into. Anyway, with Splitter, you get an `Iterable` / `List` as a result which is preferable to array and is what you're doing according to your code, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This [works](http://ideone.com/LlKJ9d) as you'd expect.

```
String string = "####";
String[] parts = string.split("#",-1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Gives `[, , , ,]`

Documentation says "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.". The `split()` method takes a `limit` parameter which is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)).

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If n
>   is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the
>   pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have
>   any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [overload of `split` that takes an `int` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and pass a negative value, trailing blank items would not be removed from the resultant array:

```
String[] splitValues = splitString.split("#", -1);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/Kbg5lf)

This produces `{"2000", "", "1000", "", "", "", ""}` array.